# SWT browser not working properly in RCP application

Tags: html, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am using SWT browser in RCP application. When I call this URL in browser by code,

```
browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
browser.setUrl("fakepath/version3/login.html"); 
browser.clearSessions();
```

Webpage was not opened properly. Although I have ensure that it conforms to CSS in IE as well. Please see the attached image. Do I need to add set any property in the meta tag? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You should find out what actual browser version SWT uses and then see if your web page renders correctly in a standalone version of that browser.Note, that you can give a hint which browser engine SWT should use with `SWT.MOZILLA` and `SWT.WEBKIT`. Though these flags are hints and may not yield the exact same results on all platforms.

Comment: Add SWT.MOZILLA and SWT.WEBKIT, it not works in my code.In the mean time if i clear the cache of IE, i got the stable web page.so, is there is any java code to clear cache.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't clear IE's cache from SWT.

Comment: yes, manually i have done clear IE's cache, but programmatically it's not work.